# I can't get the background to fade in

Tags: css

I've made a help text box that opens on click and a separate div for a transparent background to surround it. I want the background to fade in when you open this.

```
.black_overlay {                   
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

This code just doesn't want to work though, any suggestions?

Comment: We need to see a reproducible code snippet. This CSS you've given leaves too much to be guessed for it to be useful for other people.

Comment: You can't animate display property in css. Might have to set a timeout in JavaScript to animate the opacity then trigger the display property.

Comment: This is the html it's related to: <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
And it opens when this is clicked:
<img src="HelpButton.png" style="width:63px;height:80px;position:relative;left:443px;bottom:60px;cursor:pointer;" a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">